# How can I obtain filename of own MSI/EXE installer file?

Tags: installscript

I need to get a filename of the own installation package within an InstallScript function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SETUPEXEDIR and SETUPEXENAME are MSI properties. You can obtain their values through the MsiGetProperty function. If you are not using an MSI then you can use the PACKAGE_LOCATION system variable, as in

```
ParsePath(svSetupExeFileName, PACKAGE_LOCATION, FILENAME);
```

Comment: SETUPEXENAME did the job, since I need an installer exe filename, not the "original database" name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the filename:

```
function ShowInstallerFilename(hMSI)
    NUMBER maxPath;
    STRING originalDatabase;
begin
    maxPath = MAX_PATH;
    if(MsiGetProperty(hMSI, "OriginalDatabase", originalDatabase, maxPath) == ERROR_SUCCESS) then
        SprintfBox(INFORMATION, "Deferred Execution", "Original database is %s", originalDatabase);
    endif;

    MessageBox("Done", INFORMATION);
end;
```

Comment: As it turned out this doesn't solve my problem, since I needed the filename rather than "original database" name.